# Bind and scope ng-repeat json elements

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I've made a food take-out app and I'm trying to send the result using mandrill email. I'm able to use input form and send emails, however, I'm not able to bind and scope the filtered json ng-repeat results based on user selection. Relevant HTML below:

```
<md-card>
<md-card-content>
<h3 class="md-subhead" align="center">Review And Submit Order</h3>
<md-divider></md-divider>
<md-list ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <h3><div style="text-align: left;" ng-bind-html="item.name"></div><span style="float: left;">Qty:{{item.qty}}</span></h3>
    <span flex></span>
    <h3>{{ item.price | currency }}</h3>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <span>Side: {{item.type}}</span>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="item in item.flavors | filter:true">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span flex></span>
    <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="item in item.sizes | filter:true">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span flex></span>
    <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
<md-divider></md-divider>
<md-list>
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <h3 class="md-subhead">Order Total:</h3>
    <span flex></span>
    <h3 ng-model="pricetotal">{{ total(items.results) | currency }}</h3>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
</md-card-content>
</md-card>
 <md-card ng-if="(items.results | filter : {active: true}).length > 0">
 <md-card-content layout-padding>

<form name="order">
 <md-input-container flex>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input ng-model="name">
 </md-input-container>
 <md-input-container flex>
     <label>Phone</label>
  <input ng-model="phone">
 </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input ng-model="address">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input ng-model="email">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Options</label>
    <textarea ng-model="options" 
              columns="1" 
              md-maxlength="150"></textarea>
  </md-input-container>
</form>

 </md-card-content>
 <md-card-content layout="row" layout-align="end center">
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-controller="EmailController" ng-click=sendMail()>
    Place Order
</md-button>

</md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

So, basically, I want to bind $scope.menu to item.name with item.type, item.name in item.flavors and item.name in item.sizes separately and $scope.total to total(items.results) separately. Once I bind these values, I wish to send them out to email via Mandrill.

Here's my EmailController:

```
app.controller('EmailController', function($scope, $http, $mdToast, OrderFunctions) {

  $scope.showSuccessToast = function() {
    $mdToast.show({
      position: "top",
      template: "<md-toast style='background-color:#3F51B5;'>Your order has been sent. Thank you!</md-toast>"
    });
  };
  $scope.showErrorToast = function() {
    $mdToast.show({
      position: "top",
      template: "<md-toast style='background-color:#3F51B5;'>Order not sent. Please check your internet connection.</md-toast>"
    });
  };

  $scope.total = OrderFunctions.total;
  $scope.totalOrder = OrderFunctions.totalOrder;

  $scope.sendMail = function() {
    var mailJSON = {
      "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX", //your mandrill key goes here
      "message": {
      "html": "<h1>New Order</h1><p>You have received a new order from:</p><p>Name: *|NAME|*<br>Phone: *|PHONE|*<br>Address: *|ADDRESS|*<br>Email: *|EMAIL|*<br>Options: *|OPTIONS|*</p><p>They would like:</p><p>*|ITEMS|*</p><p>Order Total is: *|TOTAL|*</p>",
        "merge_vars": [{
          "rcpt": "management@signsrestaurant.ca", //your email addy here
          "vars": [{
                        "name": "NAME",
                        "content": $scope.name
                    },{
                        "name": "PHONE",
                        "content": $scope.phone
                    },{
                        "name": "ADDRESS",
                        "content": $scope.address
                    },{
                        "name": "EMAIL",
                        "content": $scope.email
                    },{
                        "name": "OPTIONS",
                        "content": $scope.options
                    },{
                        "name": "ITEMS",
                        "content": $scope.menu
                    },{
                        "name": "TOTAL",
                        "content": "$"+$scope.total+".00"
          }]
        }],
        "text": "",
        "subject": "New Order Received", // change subject here
        "from_email": "management@signsrestaurant.ca", //change from email here
        "from_name": "Signs Restaurant", //change from name here
        "to": [{
          "email": "management@signsrestaurant.ca", //your email here
          "name": "New Order", //subject here
          "type": "to"
        }],
        "merge": true,
        "important": false,
        "track_opens": null,
        "track_clicks": null,
        "auto_text": null,
        "auto_html": null,
        "inline_css": null,
        "url_strip_qs": null,
        "preserve_recipients": null,
        "view_content_link": null,
        "tracking_domain": null,
        "signing_domain": null,
        "return_path_domain": null
      },
      "async": false,
      "ip_pool": "Main Pool"
    };
    var apiURL = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json";
    $http.post(apiURL, mailJSON).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.showSuccessToast();
      $scope.form = {}; //this clears the form after success
      console.log('successful email send.');
      console.log('status: ' + status);
      console.log('data: ' + data);
      console.log('headers: ' + headers);
      console.log('config: ' + config);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.showErrorToast();
      console.log('error sending email.');
      console.log('status: ' + status);
    });
    //use these to only clear certain fields  
    /*
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.phone = "";
    $scope.address = "";
    $scope.email = "";
    $scope.clearCart();
    */
  };
});
```

I've tried the following:
I changed this

```
    <md-list ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
```

to

```
    <md-list ng-repeat="item in (menu = items.results | filter:true)">
```

in which case, I think I would have to define $scope.menu, but it seems way too complicated to define the same. I would appreciate any hints on approaching this. I'm fairly new to angularjs, but have managed to figure out most things. The idea is to get the filtered ng-repeat json data from that page and send it via email on clicking a button 'Place Order.' Thanks in advance!

Here's a plunker I'm working on:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4ByCDzXZfRU7kMX9oURT?p=preview
The JS are all in index.html, EmailController starts from line 345. The HTML is in order.html

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, my problem is further down due to the fact that I have 2 ng-repeat functions one below the other. Here is what I tried; my changed HTML:

```
<md-card>
<md-card-content>
<h3 class="md-subhead" align="center">Review And Submit Order</h3>
<md-divider></md-divider>
<md-list ng-repeat="item in filteredmenu = (items.results | filter:true)">
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <h3><div style="text-align: left;" ng-bind-html="item.name"></div><span style="float: left;">Qty:{{item.qty}}</span></h3>
    <span flex></span>
    <h3>{{ item.price | currency }}</h3>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <span>Side: {{item.type}}</span>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="item in filteredflavors = (item.flavors | filter:true)">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span flex></span>
    <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
  </md-list-item>
  <md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="item in filteredsizes = (item.sizes | filter:true)">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span flex></span>
    <span>{{ item.price | currency }}</span>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
<md-divider></md-divider>
<md-list>
  <md-list-item layout="row">
    <h3 class="md-subhead">Order Total:</h3>
    <span flex></span>
    <h3 ng-model="pricetotal">{{ pricetotal=(total(items.results) | currency) }}</h3>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
</md-card-content>
</md-card>
 <md-card ng-if="(items.results | filter : {active: true}).length > 0">
 <md-card-content layout-padding>

<form name="order">
 <md-input-container flex>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input ng-model="name">
 </md-input-container>
 <md-input-container flex>
     <label>Phone</label>
  <input ng-model="phone">
 </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input ng-model="address">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input ng-model="email">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Options</label>
    <textarea ng-model="options" 
              columns="1" 
              md-maxlength="150"></textarea>
  </md-input-container>
</form>

 </md-card-content>
 <md-card-content layout="row" layout-align="end center">
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-controller="EmailController" ng-click=sendMail()>
    Place Order
</md-button>

</md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

I added this script to my Email controller:

```
  $scope.filteredmenu = function (filteredmenu){
    var order = " ";
  angular.forEach(filteredmenu, function(item) {
    var flavor = " ";
    var size = " ";
    order += item.name + ", Qty: " + item.qty + " , ";
    angular.forEach(filteredflavors, function(option) {
      flavor += "Flavor: " + option.name + " , ";
    });
    angular.forEach(filteredsizes, function(option) {
      size += "Size: " + option.name + " , ";
    });
    menuorder += order + size + flavor;
  });
  return menuorder;
  };
```

I am abel to get the result for $scope.pricetotal, but not for $scope.filteredmenu; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, basically do you want to to get the filtered result in your controller?

Comment: Exactly, yes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your filtered list to a new scope model and use this model to send emails.

For example, you want get filtered list of `item.sizes` from the below code,

```
<md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="item in item.sizes | filter:true">
```

Just assign your filtered `item.size` to a new model like this,

```
<md-list-item layout="row" ng-repeat="item in (filteredSize = item.sizes | filter:true) ">
```

So now, you new variable `$scope.filteredSize` will have the filtered list.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I got that. My problem is further down, in defining the new variable. Let me explain; when I use {{ pricetotal = (total(items.results) | currency) }} and use $scope.pricetotal, I get the total price, no problems. For the other parts though, I can't seem to get those values as they are values present under 2 ng-repeat filters. I've explained my problem in my EDIT (hopefully, I did a better job explaining this time). Really appreciate your time.